# Ubuntu terminal opens as root user and forgot "code ." how to fix? picture included

Tags: django, windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Ubuntu crashed when I had the shell open for a django server. When it rebooted and everytime since, it opens me as the root user. How do I change it back to open me as user?

Second, I can find my way back to the user via su username(I found this command via stack overflow). But it seems to have forgotten everything I set up. Like it no longer knows the command "code ." for VS code Any idea on how this happened and what I should do to fix it. See picture below

[image]